# how to make 2 span under mat-option to have left and right align in angular material auto complete

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

i am using angular material auto complete, here i have option dropdown where i have 2 span 1st span must be left align and 2nd span to be left, i tried with absolute position setting to 2nd span but responsiveness gives issue.

Html:

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input #stateInput (keyup)="0" matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="stateInput.value !=undefined && onEnter($event)" *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{state.flag}}" height="25" />
        <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
        <span>Population: {{state.population}}</span>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-wujuas?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the spans into another tag, then apply the `display:flex` and `justify-content:space-betweeen` to that new tag.

You also need to stretch the span width to both the new tag and the Material `.mat-option-text`, I applied a `width:100%` for instance to take the whole space available.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-vist8h?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.css) is your code updated.